# Excel If Statement - Calculation Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using an Excel IF statement (`=IF(F##=L##, "T", "False")`) to double check some numbers, but it is not working properly.  I have numbers entered in Column `F` representing currency and in Column `L` an equation that calculates what the numbers in `F` should be.  The problem is that whenever the values in both columns are less than 1000 it returns `False` even when the values displayed in the columns are equivalent.
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: `TRUE` and `FALSE` are valid keywords in Excel, no need to put them in strings unless you really want that

Comment: I decided to use strings because I only care if the output is "False" and with a string I could make that condition stand out better because it is longer.  I could have used conditional formatting, but that would take a little more time to set up.

Comment: yes `=IF(F##=L##, "T", FALSE)` also prints out `FALSE` with the same length

Comment: @Luu: if you have enough width,  then yes,  you're right,  however if you decrease column wish then you'll get `###` for `FALSE ()`, while it'll be e.g. `FAL` for `"FALSE"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be generally two issues: number stored as text or rounding.

I think in your case it's rounding,  the parts displayed are the same,  but there are small differences.

For comparison use
`IF(ABS(F##-L##)<0.01,...)`

Comment: That works, thanks.  However, I still don't understand why the error would only appear when the numbers are less than 1000.  If it was a rounding error, you would think it would appear with the larger numbers and not the smaller numbers.  (With 100% consistency every number below 1000 was marked with "False", while every number above 1000 was marked as "T".  There was even a value of "1,004.05" that was between a lot of numbers less than 1000 that followed this pattern.)

Comment: I'd need to see your calculation formula to help. Precision heavily depends on that.